# US Visa application question

Tags: visas, usa, switzerland, f1-visas

In the application for US Visa I found the following question:
[image]

I am confused about the first two. For the first question, I have a US driver's license but I am not sure if that is considered as a identity card.
For the second question, I do not understand what they mean by a right.
Does anyone know about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The first question is asking if you have a passport, national ID card, or [refugee documents](https://citizenpath.com/faq/refugee-travel-document/) that can serve as a passport for international travel purposes. They don’t mean a USA drivers license, which are issued by individual states and can’t be used for international travel (they could in the past for travel to Mexico/Canada, but not since post-911).
2. With the second question, they are trying to screen out those people who are stateless without documentation or those who’ve had their right of travel revoked (such as criminals).

Note that #1 doesn't imply #2 and vice versa: i.e., one could "have" a physical passport even though the right to have said passport has been revoked (say, because of criminal activity or because one's citizenship itself was revoked or annulled). Or one could have the right to have a passport but not gotten a physical passport yet (for example, a child). So they need to ask both questions.

Comment: In Europe ID cards are very common. Official (more then driver license: issued by political authority, not road authority), and handy to bring with you. No places for stamps, but useable for nearby countries. It has also std IATA machine readable block.